# How to use enum values as columns in a GRDB Record?

Tags: ios, swift, grdb

I want to make record of 4 different types. I have the following code

```
import GRDB

enum RecordType: Int16 {
    case video, image, text, rep
}
extension RecordType: DatabaseValueConvertible {}

struct Record: Codable, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {
    var id: Int64?
    var type: RecordType
}
```

Right now it complains `Type 'Record' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Of course when I remove the type from the struct, that complaint goes away. Since type is technically Int16 why does this make it not Decodable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I adopt Codable to the RecordType as well this goes away. Found the answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

```
extension RecordType: DatabaseValueConvertible, Codable {}
```